# Como inserir 200 novos registros?

Tags: sql, select, sql-insert

Eu preciso inserir novos dados em uma tabela, mas são muitos.
eu fiz assim:

```
insert into pessoafisica (coluna1, coluna2, coluna 30) select (dado1 dado2 dado30)
```

Mas são muitos, não da pra fazer de 1 por 1. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: De todo jeito será assim. Voce pode usar php, com arrays declarados com os valores, depois um `for` para percorrer os arrays e fazer o select.

Comment: Sem saber que tipo de dados são, e o schema das tabelas envolvidas, fica dificil ajudar. Seja mais especifico no seu problema, adicione o schema das tabelas. Se for de uma tabela pra outras, é possivel usando store procedure ou function.

Comment: Dados reais ou de teste?

Comment: Acho que você precisa detalhar um pouco mais o seu problema.

Comment: acho que você consegue fazer com loop, assim: begin
 for R in(
  select dado1, dado2, dado30 from tabela
 )
 loop
  insert into tabela2 values(R.dado1, R.dado2, R.dado30);
 end loop;
end;

Comment: Já sei como é. No select eu coloquei o nome das colunas e ele já pega todos os dados daquela coluna de uma vez.

Comment: Você precisaria especificar de onde o dados estão vindo se é de uma tabela, sistema ou Excel ....

Comment: eu importei do excel para o banco

Answer (score 3):

Duas possibilidades:

- **Inserções sequenciais**

Você pode concatenar instruções `INSERT` da sequinte maneira:

```
INSERT INTO pessoafisica (coluna1, coluna2, coluna30) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO pessoafisica (coluna1, coluna2, coluna30) VALUES (4, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO pessoafisica (coluna1, coluna2, coluna30) VALUES (7, 8, 9);
```

Ao final da preparação da sequência, você pode executar todos os inserts com uma única requisição.

- **Coleção via UNION**

Concatene todos os valores a serem inseridos em uma coleção em memória, via UNION, para então inseri-los na tabela destino:

```
INSERT INTO pessoafisica (coluna1, coluna2, coluna30) 
SELECT * FROM 
     (SELECT 1, 2, 3 UNION
      SELECT 4, 5, 6 UNION
      SELECT 7, 8, 9);
```

Dependendo da tecnologia (MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) você também tem à sua disposição métodos de `BULK INSERT` (inserção em massa).

Comment: *Downvoter*, sinta-se à vontade para apontar o problema em minha resposta; agradeço.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: É sempre um prazer ajudar, @Laiane.

Answer (score 0):

Inserção contendo múltiplos valores:

```
insert into nome_tabela VALUES
('foo 1', 'f1'),
('foo 2', 'f2'),
('foo 3', 'f3')
```

Isso equivale ao mesmo que executar o insert 3 vezes:

```
insert into nome_tabela VALUES ('foo 1', 'f1');
insert into nome_tabela VALUES ('foo 2', 'f2');
insert into nome_tabela VALUES ('foo 3', 'f3');
```

A diferença é que a primeira forma é um único statement. Na segunda forma são 3, os quais consomem mais processos.

Comment: A tabela que eu importei do excel pro banco de dados tinha 1000 linhas, não dava pra inserir de 1 por 1. Obrigada pela ajuda